# parse json subclass in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

i have a function named btc_price()

```
def btc_price():
    btc_request = requests.get("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy", timeout=5)
    btc_json = json.loads(btc_request.text)
    print(btc_json['amount'])
```

that will return an error, the output of coinbases api is

```
{"data": {"base": "BTC", "currency": "USD", "amount": "34375.68"}}
```

its in data ->amount, how would I access that data? im trying to print out the btc price from coinbases api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. You need to first index the 'data' entry in your main dictionary, and then 'amount' in the dictionary within.

```
print(btc_json['data']['amount'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the path to the data you want to access is, as you mentioned, `data->amount`, a possible way of doing it is:

```py
def btc_price():
    btc_response = requests.get("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/buy", timeout=5)
    btc_json = btc_response.json()
    print(btc_json['data']['amount'])
```

Note that the response object from `requests` already has a `json` parser [built-in](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)